# TableRow not wrapping TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

TableLayout has a `TextView` and `EditText` on each row. When `EditText` has a multiple row, `TableRow` wraps it but when `TextEdit`, it doesn't..

Simplyfied layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Foo" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Foo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Renders:[image: Render 1]

But when both controls are `TextEdit`, it renders correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Foo" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Foo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Renders as: [image: Render 2]

What should i do for Android to render first layout correctly?

Ps:  I have already tried to add `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`,`android:layout_height="wrap_content`" attributes to `TableRow`, `TextView`, `EditText` controls, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B0B0B0" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

these Gray cells r textboxes

[image]

Comment: So what is the correlation between this answer and the question?

Comment: just enter the text value in it and you will find how to render the text in tablerows

Comment: As i mention on question, when both controls are TextEdit, it renders correctly.

Comment: I tried to add xml attributes one by one.. Just adding  android:background="#B0B0B0" to EditText makes android render correct layout. Strange..

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and what solved everything was setting a weight to the textviews i wanted to word wrap.

My two cents...

Comment: Ridiculous :D:D:D

Comment: Wow, it actually works!  Somehow the weight overcomes (by side effect no doubt) a bug in TextView.  Here's the command for those interested to add to you TextView's xml layout:  `android:layout_weight="1"`.  Yup, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

to the TableLayout try adding

```
 android:stretchColumns="*"
```

and if tat too doesnt work try adding weights

```
                <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" >


And to the TextView and EditText add 
              android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding  `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to `TextView` or adding  `android:background="#B0B0B0"` to `EditText` forces android to render correctly.